# Did medieval Korean phonologists consider sibilants as a separate place of articulation?

Tags: history-of-korean, phonology

Recall the medieval classification of Korean consonants:

- 순음(脣音): ㅁ, ㅂ, ㅍ
- 설음(舌音): ㄴ, ㄷ, ㅌ
- 치음(齒音): ㅅ, ㅈ, ㅊ
- 아음(牙音): ㄱ, ㅋ, ㆁ
- 후음(喉音): ㅇ, ㆆ, ㅎ
- 반설음(半舌音): ㄹ
- 반치음(半齒音): ㅿ

순음 is bilabial, 설음 is coronal, 아음 is dorsal, and 후음 is glottal. Yet there is odd one out: 치음 marks sibilant, which is a manner of articulation, and not a place of articulation.

Is this because medieval Korean phonologists indeed classified sibilants as a separate place of articulation, or because they're just the "odd one out"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Korean separation of 설음 (coronals, literally 'tongue sound') and 치음 (affricates and sibilants, literally 'teeth sound') can be seen in the companion to the 훈민정음 (訓民正音, *Hunminjeong'eum*), the 동국정운 (東國正韻, *Dongguk Jeong'un*) from the 1440s.

But this split of the 설음 from the 치음 is already found in Chinese 韻書 'rime dictionaries', including the 韻鏡 *Yùnjìng* from the year 1161 (Song dynasty). This is part of the "36 initials", where the dental stop series (舌頭音 *shétóuyīn*) 端透定泥 and the palatal/retroflex series (舌上音 *shéshàngyīn*) 知徹澄娘 are both called 舌音 and listed under the pentatonic note name 徵 (*zhǐ*), whereas the dental affricate-sibilant (齒頭音 *chǐtóuyīn*) series 精清從心邪 and palatal/retroflex affricate-sibilant (正齒音 *zhèngchǐyīn*) series 照穿牀審禪 are in 齒音 and under the pentatonic note name 商 (*shāng*).

The concept of the initials of Chinese (in their order) is attested earlier, from the Tang dynasty, from a manuscript by the Buddhist monk 守温 *Shǒuwēn*. The 30 initials there also show the distinction between coronal stops and affricates/sibilants, but with 心 and 邪 placed under 喉音 (*hóuyīn*) rather than 齒音. This has parallels with *ungrouped* (अवर्ग *avárga*) consonants in the phonology of Indic languages, not surprising considering the Buddhist nature of these manuscripts.

But upon comparison with the Sanskrit वर्ग (*várga*) system, we see that this distinction arose very much within the Chinese phonological tradition. As stated by Jacques 2017 in the *Encyclopedia of Chinese Language and Linguistics*:

> An indirect Indic origin for the rhyme tables is probable, but in any case the
> Chinese scholar who established the rhyme table tradition and its terminology did
> not slavishly translate the Sanskrit terms, but rather invented a new framework
> inspired by them.